# I accidentically made a super small mesh or something?

Tags: mesh

I downloaded blender an hour ago, and I am doing the donut tutorial from Blender Guru.
The problem is, that I accidentally pressed something and I made a super small grid thing.
I couldn't undo it with <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image: This is what it looks like.]

Comment: Is there a subdivision modifier used in the tutorial? If so you might have applied it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two solutions

The first and most likely solution is that you have accidentally changed the scale of the donut. You can check this by pressing <kbd>N</kbd> on the keyboard and navigating to the *item* panel. From there, check that the *scale* is set to 1.0

[image]

The other solution might be to re-check the viewport overlay to check that the *scale* is set to 1.0

[image]